# BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE fails even if the two values are below the threshold

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I'm performing unit testing using boost. When I use BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE I get this failure message:

```
difference{inf%} {-6.9388939e-18} and (0.0){0} exceeds 1.0000000000000001e-05%
```

It sounds weird to me as the difference between -6.9388939e-18 and 0.0 is below 1.0000000000000001e-05%. Furthermore, I do no understand why it says that the difference is infinite.

Any idea about the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE` uses Knuth's tolerance predicate to compare floating point numbers, which is

```
abs(x - y) / abs(x) <= eps && abs(x - y) / abs(y) <= eps
```

Where `x`, `y` are the numbers to compare and `eps` is the tolerance epsilon. In other words, it tests that `x` is not more than `eps` percent<sup>1</sup> of `x` away from `y`, and vice versa.

This predicate has many properties to recommend it (particularly when working with very big or very small numbers, or when the orders of magnitude of `x` and `y` are not known/fixed), but a drawback is that it has a singularity at zero (nothing is close to zero, according to it, because `eps` percent of zero is zero, leading to a tolerance of zero), and that is the problem you ran into.

You can replace it with

```
BOOST_CHECK_SMALL(x - y, epsilon);
```

to use an absolute epsilon value<sup>2</sup>. Or, since I assume the zero in your test is a fixed number, just

```
BOOST_CHECK_SMALL(x, epsilon);
```

<sup>1</sup> `BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE` interprets the given epsilon as percentage. I have always wondered why.
<sup>2</sup> Note that `BOOST_CHECK_SMALL` does not interpret the given epsilon as a percentage but as an absolute value.

Comment: A very clear answer and the solution works perfectly! Thanks a lot!